# Opacity CSS that works for all browsers?

Tags: css, opacity

Can someone recommend the safest approach for giving an OPACITY VALUE to a DIV TAG using CSS?

Erik

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Straight from [Css-Tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/) (this covers everything I can think of):

```
.transparent_class {
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: If i want the transparency to 100% is it "1" or "1.0"?

Comment: 100% transparency = 0 -- because the setting is Opacity.

Comment: What about IE9 and IE10 ?

Comment: @basZero - IE9 and 10 should either use the `-ms-filter` or `opacity`.

Answer (score 6):

This will work in every browser.

```
div {
 -khtml-opacity:.50; 
 -moz-opacity:.50; 
 -ms-filter:”alpha(opacity=50)”;
  filter:alpha(opacity=50);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.5);
  opacity:.50; 
}
```

**Or you can use jQuery and do it in a single line**

```
$('div').css({opacity:0.5});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/397jv/

Answer (score 0):

Although CSS 3 introduces the new opacity feature for transparency, it does not support all browsers. This is a CSS trick for transparency in all browsers

```
.transparent_class {  
 filter: alpha(opacity=50);  
 -moz-opacity: 0.5;  
 -khtml-opacity: 0.5;  
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```