# How to change opacity?

Tags: html, css

How to change opacity of a single element in div with opacity? I have this div called "circle"

```
.circle{
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    border-radius: 32px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Ther is a div with facebook logo inside of this div. The problem is I don't know how to change opacity of facebook logo or completely turn off opacity on this element.

Comment: Well, there's an `opacity` property right there in the CSS... Did you try changing that value?

Comment: Here's a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640815/opacity-css-that-works-for-all-browsers. I guess you need it to be cross browser too.You can find the answer there too

Comment: Yea I tried, but the whole element changed his opacity insted of only facebook logo.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change it for only one of them you could give that element an class 'FBlogo' and apply the opacity for items with the class of circle and FBlogo. So you would have

```
.circle{
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    border-radius: 32px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.circle.FBlogo{
    opacity: //your value;
}
```